# MapFragment, GoogleMap .getMap()

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am having a lot of trouble getting `.getMap()` to work when trying to create a `GoogleMap` object (it is returning null), I have looked around and seen people had similar issues but wasn't able to find any help from any of them. In it's current implementation how can I find the `MapFragment` & create a `GoogleMap` from it?

```
protected void setFragment(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment mapFragment =  MapFragment.newInstance();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mapFragment).commit();

    try{
        GoogleMap gMap = ((MapFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)).getMap();
        gMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    }catch(Exception e){  }

}
```

The portion of XML containing fragment_container

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/selectionLayout">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp">


    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow the `Map` to load before you start using otherwise you'll get `null`. You have the `onReady` callback when the map is ready for use.

```
protected void setFragment(){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment mapFragment =  MapFragment.newInstance();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mapFragment).commit();

    try{
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                //your map related actions.
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @DanielNugent good catch! It was a duplicate variable as well. I just copy pasted the code from the question.

Comment: Accepted as answer, however it was missing a required closing parenthesis which I requested as an edit. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You actually need to include a fragment (NOT the Relative Layout) to your layout like so:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: If you look at their code, they are adding the map programmatically. This does not answer the question of retrieving the `GoogleMap` object

Comment: The fragments are being dynamically / programmatically added during run time of the app.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Refer to Harish's answer then.